# Not able to show alert on hyperlink click

Tags: javascript

I have an anchor link and on its click I call a JavaScript function and I am using if-else in it. if condition is true it works fine goes to the link.but if condition is false.I am displaying alert to the user.But My alert is not working.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

         function getVal(fid) {

             if (fid != null || fid != undefined || fid != "")
                 window.location = "http://yatra.eresolute.com/Airline/AirPrice.aspx?fid=" + fid.toString();
             else
                 alert("Flight has no ID!");

         }

    </script>
```

Comment: Add your HTML markup to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your condition's `undefined` to

```
if (fid != null && typeof(fid) != 'undefined' && fid != "")
```

Also try to `alert(fid)` before `if` condition.

Answer (score 1):

You're misleading on

```
if (fid != null || fid != undefined || fid != "")
```

You should be using `&&` instead of `||`.

Why ?

Because `||` means *or* and, `fid`, in every case, can't be null and undefined and an empty string at the same time. In your code, you're saying that

> if it's not null OR not undefined OR an empty string, then redirect

Your check must be positive on those 3 verifications.
So, 2 choices :

```
if (fid != null && fid != undefined && fid != "") {window.location...}else{alert(...)}
```

Or

```
if (fid == null || fid == undefined || fid == "") {alert(...)}else{window.location...}
```

Comment: Ah, I'd overlooked that. I thought the condition looked ugly and over-complicated, but.. hadn't seen the error.

Comment: @user2164964: Why didn't you say it was redirecting, rather than showing the alert?

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution

http://jsfiddle.net/p9z3F/

```
function getVal(fid) {
    if (fid != null && fid != undefined && fid != "") alert('Flight have ID')
    else alert("Flight has no ID!");
}
```

Comment: Davor if fid has value I need to redirect it to another page otherwise i need to show alert.

Comment: then instead of `alert('Flight have ID')` you put your redirection sentence.